# Pandas: Date difference loop between columns with similiar names (ACD and ECD)

Tags: pandas, loops, numpy, jupyter

I'm working in Jupyter and have a large number of columns, many of them dates. I want to create a loop that will return a new column with the date difference between two similarly-named columns.

For example:

```
df['Site Visit ACD']
df['Site Visit ECD']
df['Sold ACD (Loc A)']
df['Sold ECD (Loc A)']
```

The new column will have a column df['Site Visit Cycle Time'] = date difference between ACD and ECD. Generally, it will always be the column that contains "ACD" minus the column that contains "ECD". How can I write this?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do the following:

1. Find columns that are similar (over 90 ratio fuzz using fuzzywuzzy package)
2. Perform the date comparison (or time)
3. Avoid the same computation to be performed on both sides
4. get the name 'Site Visit' if the column is called more or less like that
5. get the name 'difference between 'column 1' and 'column 2' if it is called differently

I hope it helps.

```
import pandas as pd
    from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
    name = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', sheet_name='name')
    unique = []
    for i in name.columns:
        for j in name.columns:
            if i != j and fuzz.ratio(i, j) > 90 and i+j not in unique:
                if 'Site Visit' in i:
                    name['Site Visit'] = name[i] - name[j]
                else:
                    name['difference between '+i+' and '+j] = name[i] - name[j]
                unique.append(j+i)
                unique.append(i+j)
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Generally, it will always be the column that contains "ACD" minus the column that contains "ECD".

This answer assumes the column titles are not noisy, i.e. they only differ in "ACD" / "ECD" and are exactly the same apart from that (upper/lower case included). Also assuming that there always is a matching column. This code doesn't check if it overwrites the column it writes the date difference to.

This approach works in linear time, as we iterate over the set of columns once and directly access the matching column by name.

**test.csv**

```
Site Visit ECD,Site Visit ACD,Sold ECD (Loc A),Sold ACD (Loc A)
2018-06-01,2018-06-04,2018-07-05,2018-07-06
2017-02-22,2017-03-02,2017-02-27,2017-03-02
```

**Code**

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", delimiter=",")

for col_name_acd in df.columns:
    # Skip columns that don't have "ACD" in their name
    if "ACD" not in col_name_acd: continue

    col_name_ecd = col_name_acd.replace("ACD", "ECD")

    # we assume there is always a matching "ECD" column
    assert col_name_ecd in df.columns

    col_name_diff = col_name_acd.replace("ACD", "Cycle Time")
    df[col_name_diff] = df[col_name_acd].astype('datetime64[ns]') - df[col_name_ecd].astype('datetime64[ns]')

print(df.head())
```

**Output**

```
  Site Visit ECD Site Visit ACD Sold ECD (Loc A) Sold ACD (Loc A)  \
0     2018-06-01     2018-06-04       2018-07-05       2018-07-06   
1     2017-02-22     2017-03-02       2017-02-27       2017-03-02   

  Site Visit Cycle Time Sold Cycle Time (Loc A)  
0                3 days                  1 days  
1                8 days                  3 days
```

Comment: Thanks @snwflk . A small amount of the columns have blank cells. If I want to incorporate logic into this loop that says "if either of these columns are blank skip this row or just return a blank" how could I do that?

Comment: What happens right now in those cases? Are you getting `ValueError`s when trying to convert to `datetime`? In that case, you could use a `try` block around the last line of the loop body.